# Type based on property inside of same type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to make a component that allows props based on another prop inside the type.

What I'm trying to achieve kind of feels like a [Discriminated Union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), but the difference is I want the discriminator to be an array of literals and to be able to return an intersection of multiple types based on what's in the property.

So given the following definitions:

```js
type Variant = 'select' | 'drag'

// Common interface that defines props available no matter what functionality is required
interface CommonProps {
  variant: Variant[]
  title: string
}

// Drag interface specifying props only available when drag functionality is required
interface DragProps extends CommonProps {
  onDrag: () => void
}

// Select interface specifying props only available when select functionality is required
interface SelectProps extends CommonProps {
  onSelect: () => void
}

const ComponentWithRequiredFeatures = (props: MagicTypeProps) => {
  ...
}
```

I am trying to make some `MagicTypeProps` that will allow me for this component to be used as such:

```js
// Error: Property 'onDrag' does not exist on type
<ComponentWithRequiredFeatures variant={['select']} title="Hello world" onSelect={() => {}} onDrag={() => {}} />

// Error: Property 'onSelect' is missing
<ComponentWithRequiredFeatures variant={['select', 'drag']} title="Hello world" onDrag={() => {}} />

// Okay
<ComponentWithRequiredFeatures variant={['select', 'drag']} title="Hello world" onSelect={() => {}} onDrag={() => {}} />
```

So based on the `variant` prop, I'm expecting `MagicTypeProps` to be some version of an intersection of the original types.

For example:

if `variant` is `['select']`, then `MagicTypeProps` would be `SelectProps`

if `variant` is `['select', 'drag']`, then it would be `SelectProps & DragProps`.

#### What I've tried so far

I've managed to achieve the same behaviour using generic types and literals, just removed the `variant` property from the `CommonProps` type above.

#### Using Generic Type

```js
// https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-980401795
export type NoInfer<T> = T extends infer S ? S : never

type GenericExtend = CommonProps | DragProps | SelectProps

const ComponentWithRequiredFeatures = <T extends GenericExtend = CommonProps>(props: NoInfer<T>) => {
  ...
}
```

This achieves the behaviour described above and produces the required errors:

```js
// Error: Property 'onDrag' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SelectProps'.
<ComponentWithRequiredFeatures<SelectProps> title="Hello world" onSelect={() => {}} onDrag={() => {}} />

// Error: Property 'onSelect' is missing in type '{ title: string; onDrag: () => void; }' but required in type 'SelectProps'.
<ComponentWithRequiredFeatures<SelectProps & DragProps> title="Hello world" onDrag={() => {}} />

// Okay
<ComponentWithRequiredFeatures<SelectProps & DragProps> title="Hello world" onDrag={() => {}} onSelect={() => {}} />
```

#### Using Generic Type with Literals

```js
// https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29594
export type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (k: infer I) => void ? I : never

type LiteralPropsMapping = {
  common: CommonProps
  select: SelectProps
  drag: DragProps
}

type Literals = keyof LiteralPropsMapping // 'common' | 'drag' | 'select'

const ComponentWithRequiredFeatures = <T extends Literals = 'common'>(
  props: UnionToIntersection<LiteralPropsMapping [T]>
) => {
  ...
}
```

This again achieves the same effect when used:

```js
// Error: Property 'onDrag' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SelectProps'.
<ComponentWithRequiredFeatures<'select'> title="Hello world" onSelect={() => {}} onDrag={() => {}} />

// Property 'onSelect' is missing in type '{ title: string; onDrag: () => void; }' but required in type 'SelectProps'.
<ComponentWithRequiredFeatures<'select' | 'drag'> title="Hello world" onDrag={() => {}} />

// Okay
<ComponentWithRequiredFeatures<'select' | 'drag'> title="Hello world" onDrag={() => {}} onSelect={() => {}} />
```

#### [Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-goldwasser-1spgxq)

I've created a Codesandbox that illustrate all of my attempts and how typechecking works with the Generic approaches, I am just lost on how to do such a thing when the constraints need to be inferred from a prop within the type.

Comment: Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/wjDAkm) what you want?

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! Could you post this as an answer so I can mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with mapping variants to their respective prop types:

```
interface VariantMap {
    select: SelectProps;
    drag: DragProps;
}
```

Your `Variant` type can then be represented as

```
type Variant = keyof VariantMap;
```

and to get the correct prop types for a union of variants, we intersect the shared `CommonProps`,

```
interface CommonProps<Variants extends Variant> {
    variant?: Variants[];
    title: string;
}
```

with each respective entry from the `VariantMap`. Using distributive conditional types, it gives us this:

```
type PropsForVariants<Variants extends Variant> = CommonProps<Variants> &
    ([Variants] extends [never] // check if it's never (not provided)
        ? {}
        : Variants extends Variant // distributes Variants
        ? VariantMap[Variants]
        : {});
```

Then, make your component generic with respect to the variants given (and defaulting to `never` if no variants are provided), we can pass the variants to the type:

```
const ComponentWithRequiredFeatures = <Variants extends Variant = never>(
    props: PropsForVariants<Variants>
) => {
    return <></>;
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgGFcQJqAFHMAZwA8ANRRRgKWnzhIAHnWoATKSLESYAPjgBvcnD1wAbqPG0A-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-zvXF84XbWoqww58DDOvN70nAAqtQ7tQIDvqI+C2fY8XFjYD9GreVODrBsmxbPUDRQMMuzApl+xsQdh1HNYJynXZZxfV8ly8VcNw8Ldd33Q8UNpU94gAy9ggIm92kWB8tAvINGOo0DXwg8AoOVNVNR1eCOxNaiXDQtQMJHViYBw-BpwCfCJP0IiV3XTdtz3KADyPV9bwOejOKYpkeJvPja0ExthNbdtEM7bsDP0KTaBkrCSEnRS8LnVS9HUkitIo3SqNfUDqMsgT6yE5sRLbBCkKc5zDFhdy5JU5LXHcYjNLI7TKP05KWM6YygMy2iAlKq9uP9XiayimDbNEhzxMy1yYDSsdfMygLcvInS9L8uBirWKquPK6hP2-X9-3Yp9qrC2qLPqxVops2K7ISxyhvazrsO65LetI-qCqGka2I4sqb3MhdItWxqNuaxKdtSodZK60zeyOoKBtC67-QilboJiuD4rE5C2te4clIyw7so0478pCwrnIqsbPvLc6OrmwCFv+wHIPukG4vs57IYHN6YYO5zvry4LBomoycYYjGRQ-L8fz-dGaoJ-iifW0HSe28n0MpnzWcXeHArp36UYMtHmZMnneastbYJJrbWrh5dpZO5GzuoJnLrxhcbt7O7gYFjXwaSmmpb6pGGaKu85O5xaVYa4nNptobab1p3UcmjmZrd-G6sJy31e9lquyynWHfpw84DN8sLesqOnsc5OlqZGMc7gSVBgoIA)

Comment: Thanks for this, @vr.!

Is this approach able to support a generic type guard at all?

Currently, when destructuring `props`, I am rightfully only able to extract props from `CommonProps`, but I want to make it so a generic type guard can allow me to destructure other props as well, so:

`if (isType<V>(props, ['drag'])) {
  // Expecting props to be of type CommonProps<V> & DragProps
  // Expecting onDrag to be available, but not onSelect, onUnknown
  const { title, variant, onDrag, onSelect, onUnknown } = props
}`

Comment: @Peter I came up with [this](https://tsplay.dev/mxkobN)

Comment: Thanks for this - it's pushed me in the right direction!
I couldn't get it to work with multiple though, so extracting props from multiple variants wouldn't work. I changed the guard type to `props is GuardTypePropsForVariants<V>`  where `type GuardTypePropsForVariants<V extends Variant> = CommonProps<V> & UnionToIntersection<VariantMap[V]>` and that seems to work now.
Any reason why the variants should be passed as multiple props rather than one array prop? I seem to prefer `variants: V[]` over `...variants: V[]`, but not sure if it's just down to preference or if there's any TS convention?